# Possibly silly question about conformal maps

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, conformal-geometry

I've been reviewing conformal maps lately and I feel like I understand them, until I reach a certain point in a problem. I'll give an example to illustrate my confusion:

In the process of constructing a conformal map $\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid |z|>1 \text{ and } z\notin (0,\infty)\}\to \{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid Re(z)>0\},$ I map the first region successfully to the upper half of the unit disk $\{z\in \mathbb{D}\mid Im(z)>0\}$ (using $z^{1/2}$ and $1/z$) and then I want to map this region onto a quadrant.

I know that the inverse of the Cayley transform (the map the takes $\mathbb{D}\to \text{Upper Half Plane}$ conformally) is $z\mapsto i\frac{1-z}{1+z},$ but I don't have any idea how to figure out the range of this function when restricted to the upper half of the unit disk.

So, **my first question** is: is there a general way to determine the range of these maps? Especially when restricting a known conformal mapping to a smaller domain?

My **second question** is: I have often seen linear fractional transformations determined by 3 points. I understand that lines and circles on $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ are determined in this way, but I get confused when it comes to disks and half planes.

For example, if I wanted to determine a linear fractional transformation from the unit disk, I would likely pick $i,-i,$ and $1.$ However, if I wanted to pick 3 more points for the upper half plane, I might pick $-1,1,$ and $\infty.$ How do I know the transformation I design will give me the upper half plane and not the lower half plane? Is there a clearer way to always pick these 3 points? Furthermore, is there an intuitive way to know where to send which point? So far, I've just been assigning them pretty randomly.

Any help and clarification is greatly appreciated!

Comment: For your first question, for calculating the range, remember that Mobius Transforms send generalized circles to generalized circles, so if possible decompose your boundary into them; in this case, your boundary a semi-circle, which is the union of a line and part of a circle. Consider some points on each to see where the function is mapping to, then consider one point inside your region and see where it maps to

Comment: For your second question, recall that Mobius Transforms preserve angles (being conformal after all) so you just consider orientation. Choose 3 points such that the interior of your region is on the left, and their image must preserve this! We thus know which side is the interior after the mapping. Thus we need only consider boundaries when defining Mobius Transforms, which is why Disks $\equiv$ Circles and Half-Planes $\equiv$ Lines

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Applying $z^{1/2}$ won't get you the upper half-plane but only the part of the half-plane outside the unit circle (because you start with $z$ outside the unit circle).